# External script error in socket.io server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having a problem, whenever I try to import a local script:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    var socket = io();
    editor.getSession().on('change', function e() {
      socket.emit('editor-change', editor.getValue());
    });

    socket.on('editor-change', function(val) {
      edit.setValue(val);
    });
</script>
```

Everything gets imported fine except the ace-builds which is in the correct directory. Here's an image of the error:

[image: N/A]

I don't understand why I'm getting this error (404) because all these files (including the server scripts) are hosted in the same directory as the file giving off the 404 error.

Comment: Do you realize that node.js does not serve any files unless you explicitly set up routes to server them or use something like express-static that can serve multiple files in a location for you.  The socket.io code sets up routes to serve socket.io/socket.io.js (it actually comes from a location in the file system different than that).

Comment: Oh @jfriend00 .. I never knew of this. Do you know of any docs where I can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default node.js does not serve any files.  If you want it to serve files, then you either have to set up specific routes to serve specific files or use a module like express-static that can serve directories of files for you.

You can read more about serving static files here: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html